# Активация учетной записи

Tags: php

> Добро пожаловать на XXXX.
> Пожалуйста, сохраните это сообщение. Параметры вашей учётной записи таковы:
>
> Имя пользователя: xxxxx
> Пароль: xxxxx
>
> Ваша учётная запись ещё не активна. Вы не сможете ей пользоваться, пока не перейдёте по следующей ссылке:
> `http://somehost/profile.php?mode=activate&u=12345&act_key=a1bc34656...`

u - вероятно id нового пользователя. Что за параметр `act_key`, причем на разных сайтах разной длины? Как сделать нечто подобное?

Answer (score 3):

При регистрации пользователя в таблицу юзеров вносятся следующие данные: идентификатор ( в нашем случае "u" ) и код активации аккаунта. Идентификатор генерируется автоинкрементов в базе, а код активации вы в скрипте допустим следующим образом:

```
srand( time() );
$act_key= MD5( rand( 999999999 ) );
```

Далее после записи пользователя в базу со всеми эти данными ему на почту отправляется письмо со ссылкой:

```
"http://site.net/act_key.php?u=12345&act_key=" . $act_key;
```

Юзер нажимает на ссылку и вы в скрипте сверяете оба параметра по базе, если верные то активируете юзера.

Comment: Вы забыли в таблице, хранящей информацию о пользователях указать флаг, говорящий о том прошел ли пользователь процедуру активации или нет. Кстати ключ активации в таблице с пользователями не нужен, это бессмысленная нагрузка на таблицу (он нужен в первые несколько часов после регистрации, а место занимать будет все время), такие вещи нужно выносить в отдельную таблицу и сопоставлять ее с идентификатором пользователя.

Comment: Согласен, можно. А так же это же поле можно использовать при восстановлении доступа к аккаунту. Много чего можно придумать :) Это только принцип.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это может быть любой сгенерированный параметр, для того, чтобы подобрать/взломать было сложнее.